# interrupting remove in awesome_nested_fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm using [awesome_nested_fields](https://github.com/lailsonbm/awesome_nested_fields) in a rails project.

I'm trying to cancel a removal of a nested field based during a callback.

```
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('form[data-validate]').nestedFields({
      beforeInsert: function(item) {
      },
      afterInsert: function (item) {
      },
      beforeRemove: function (item) {
        if(something) {
          //cancel the removal and leave the field in place.
        }
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
```

Here's a link to the js - https://github.com/lailsonbm/awesome_nested_fields/blob/master/vendor/assets/javascripts/jquery.nested-fields.js

Is this possible without editing jquery.nested-fields.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code of this lib, it seems you only need to provide a function with two argument to avoid the remove part to be called.

```
 options.beforeRemove($element, remove);
 if(options.beforeRemove.length <= 1) {
    remove();
 }
```

So explicitly providing the callback argument without calling it should work

```
beforeRemove: function (item, remove) {
        if(something) {
           //cancel the removal and leave the field in place.
        } else {
           remove();
        }
        return false;
      }
```